# Null object reference error on container.createIfNotExists();

Tags: java, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to work with Azure Blob Storage for an Android app by following the below link:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-java-how-to-use-blob-storage/

I am using Android Studio

I am going fine till I get an exception in the line:

```
container.createIfNotExists();
```

This line gives the error:

```
Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Transport.writeRequestHeaders(com.android.okhttp.Request)' on a null object reference
```

Below are my imports:

```
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.*;
```

The java code:

```
try{
            System.out.print("Code Progess 2 ");
            CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
            System.out.print("Code Progess 3 ");
            CloudBlobClient serviceClient = account.createCloudBlobClient();
            System.out.print("Code Progess 4 ");

            // Container name must be lower case.
            CloudBlobContainer container = serviceClient.getContainerReference("myimages");
            System.out.print("Code Progess 5 ");
            container.createIfNotExists();
            System.out.print("Code Progess 6 ");

            // Upload an image file.
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference("image1.jpg");
            System.out.print("Code Progess 7 ");
            File sourceFile = new File("<Path to local image storage>");
            System.out.print("Code Progess 8 ");
            blob.upload(new FileInputStream(sourceFile), sourceFile.length());
            System.out.print("Code Progess 9 ");

            // Download the image file.
            File destinationFile = new File(sourceFile.getParentFile(), "image1Download.tmp");
            System.out.print("Code Progess 10 ");
            blob.downloadToFile(destinationFile.getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.print("Code Progess 11 ");
        }

catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Exception encountered: ");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
        }
```

The logcat is as below:

```
01-09 20:54:02.072    2271-2287/com.rollcall.blob W/art﹕ Verification of void com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobContainer.create(com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobRequestOptions, com.microsoft.azure.storage.OperationContext) took 334.218ms
01-09 20:54:02.140    2271-2287/com.rollcall.blob W/art﹕ Unresolved exception class when finding catch block: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException
01-09 20:54:02.141    2271-2287/com.rollcall.blob I/System.out﹕ Code Progess 1 Code Progess 2 Code Progess 3 Code Progess 4 Code Progess 5 Exception encountered: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Transport.writeRequestHeaders(com.android.okhttp.Request)' on a null object reference
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Show us the exception stacktrace and the relevant code.

Comment: I have added stacktrace and code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getting started guide you refer to is specifically for Java. Are you using Java or Android Azure Storage client library for your sample? There is a separate android Azure Storage client library that you should use for building Android applications.

You can look at the [readme document](https://github.com/azure/azure-storage-android) on Github repository to get started. Sample code on working with blob can also be found in the repository [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-android/blob/master/microsoft-azure-storage-samples/src/com/microsoft/azure/storage/samples/blob/BlobGettingStartedTask.java)

Comment: Thanks Vinay, the repository really helped :)